# At what time does cron execute daily scripts?

Tags: scripts, cron, cron-jobs

If I place a shell script in `/etc/cron.daily/`, at what time of the day will it be executed?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Looking at `/etc/crontab` it should run at *06:25*.

```
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

Comment: This is most probably wrong because anacron is installed by default. The other answer is the correct one.

Comment: Yes, this aswer is generally misleading. If anacron is installed see @DaithiF's answer.

Answer (score 46):

Approximately 7:35am, but the exact timing will depend on anacron.

By default cron delegates the running of /etc/cron.daily jobs to anacron.  /etc/crontab contains the line:

```
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
```

but this defines the behaviour if anacron **is not installed**

With anacron installed, the running of cron.daily jobs is controlled by the entry in /etc/anacrontab:

```
1   5   cron.daily   nice run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
```

which says run these jobs once per day, with a delay of 5 minutes.

anacron itself is run by cron, as specified in the file /etc/cron.d/anacron, which runs anacron at 7:30am.

Answer (score 10):

As indicated by other answers, the result depends on whether anacron is installed. On a desktop, it is installed by default, BUT crucially it is not installed in the server distribution. So the answer is around 06:25 on a server and about 07:35 on a desktop.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the other answers, on newer systems anacron is managed by systemd. On my Ubuntu 19.10 system anacron runs from 7:30 - 23:30 every hour, with a randomized delay of 5 minutes. Anacron then runs cron.daily scripts with a 5 minute delay as defined in `/etc/anacrontab`.

In addition to that systemd only starts anacron when the system is connected to AC power. Have a look at `/lib/systemd/system/anacron.service` and `/lib/systemd/system/anacron.timer` for more info.