# The jobs specified in /etc/crontab are running at the wong time, why?

Tags: cron

I'm trying to get cron.daily to run just after midnight with the line below

> 2   0  * * * * ... (the rest is the standard verbiage)

However it is run at 
07:36   and claims to be run by anacron (I don't necessarily believe that)
What is the scoop,  Oh yeah, my system is in the PST8PDT timexome.

Comment: Afaik, `cron.daily` is managed by *Ana*cron – there's no Anacron on the system in which case it falls back to Cron. You can also see that in your `crontab` file where it only runs the `cron.daily` directory if `/usr/sbin/anacron` doesn't exist. So you're likely looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Take a look at the 2nd answer in [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36971/at-what-time-does-cron-execute-daily-scripts) question.

Comment: Perfect, I shouls have looked at the verbage because that was where the clue was,

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was in fact that anacron was running the jobs, not cron.
Anacron, which is installed on desktop machines, but NOT on servers by default (/etc/cron.d/anacron) runs the daily jobs at 0730.