# Using rsync for incremental backup

Tags: bash, ssh, backup, cron, rsync

I'm hosting a page and have ssh-access to the webspace.

The site allows modification by it's users. To be able to revert it back to an older state, I thought about rsync to create an incremental backup every 30 minutes using cron to launch the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Binaries
RSYNC=`which rsync`
LN=`which ln`
MKDIR=`which mkdir`
#TODO: Is this enough to make the script distro independent?

# Other Variables
source="<username>@<provider>:<workspace path>"
target="<local backup path>"
# Date ...
year=$(date +%Y)
month=$(date +%m)
day=$(date +%d)
# ... and time
hour=$(date +%H)
minute=$(date +%M)

# Prepare directories
$MKDIR -p $target/$year/$month/$day/"$hour"_"$minute"/
# TODO: Why is this necessary? The actual backup won't work without this line
# saying "directory does not exist...".

# Actual backup
$RSYNC -av --delete "$source" "$target/$year/$month/$day/"$hour"_"$minute"/" --link-dest="$target/latest/"
$LN -nsf "$target/$year/$month/$day/"$hour"_"$minute"/" "$target/latest"

# End script
exit 0
```

The script seems to work so far but the target-path bloated to roughly three times the actual size of the source path within in the last three days.

Incremental backuping should only lead to a small increase, right?

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Markus

Comment: How do you determine the size of your backup directories? I'm asking because I use [a similar script](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029653/504066) for years without any problems. In my case I have directories like `my-backups/2018-04-29`, `my-backups/2018-04-30`, `my-backups/2018-05-01` etc. When I do `du -hs 2018-04-29` then it returns ±200GB (=full backup), and almost the same for `du -hs 2018-04-30` ...

Comment: (continued) But when I do `du -hs 2018-04-29 2018-04-30` (i.e. both directories in one go), then it returns ±200GB for the first and just ±5GB (=incremental backup) for the second. I think in that case `du` notices that most files in …30 are hardlinked with files in …29 and only counts them once.

Comment: Is your local directory, `$target`, on an ext4 filesystem? Else the hardlinks won't work and you won't save any space.

Comment: Yes, it is a ext4-Filesystem. Using four physical disks, combined by lvm. But that shouldn't affect the characteristics of an ext4 partition, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually already a tool created that does exactly this, based on rsync. It's called rdiff-backup and I've used it many times in the past to create incremental backups and it supports rolling back to previous states. It can also be configured to clean up old backups so that your backup directory doesn't keep growing forever.

Find out more about it here and look at the usage examples on the documentation page: http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/

Answer (score 5):

If your backup media has a linux format eg ext3 or ext4 (and it probably should, or file attributes won't get backed up), then there is a neat trick you can do with rsync and cp -al making good use of a feature of the file system: you do an incremental backup, but then you create hard links to the files at each backup. This means you only copy the files that have changed but the backup media only has one copy of each file so doesn't balloon in size, (I can't take the credit for this; it was in a comment on a long-previous question that I could not begin to find again.)

My (daily) backup goes something like:

```
DEST=/media/$USER/backups         # the name my backup media is mounted under
rsync -av --progress --delete --exclude ".[!.]*"  ~/ $DEST/current
DATE=`date -I`
mkdir $DEST/$DATE
cp -al $DEST/current/ $DEST/$DATE
```

this updates "current" with only the files that have changed, but creates a directory named after today's date with hard links to all the files. Thus ls of each days backups appear to contain all the files in situ, but there is in fact only one copy on the backup media. The latter point is also the downside: as there's only one copy of each file you should rotate the media so you have multiple copies, but that is good backup practice anyway.

Comment: Indeed a neat trick, but `rsync` has a switch `--link-dest` that already creates hardlinks to another (e.g. yesterday's) directory. Basically you would say `rsync -a --delete --link-dest=$previous $source $current`.

Comment: @PerlDuck thanks I did not know about --link-dest, I don't find the man page for rsync a masterpiece of clarity! The trouble might be that to do the same thing with --link-dest you need to know the name of the last backup directory, `date -I -d yesterday` would do it for daily backups but would fail if you missed one eg on a Sunday.

Comment: Exactly. You will need to figure out the name of the previous directory yourself. See my approach [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029653/504066). Or use the OP's trick to create a symlink to the `previous` (aka `latest`) directory after doing a backup. I like that idea but didn't test how `--link-dest` behaves when given a symlink.

Comment: Why include the `mkdir $DEST/$DATE` line? This makes `cp` put the contents of `$DEST/current/` into `$DEST/$DATE/current/`. Wouldn't it be preferred if the files were simply inside `$DEST/$DATE/`?

Comment: @Andrew I agree. I use now use it with `cp -al $DEST/current/. $DEST/$DATE`, which achieves exactly that. Note the dot after the first path, this is cp syntax for "all files in this dir, including hidden files"

Answer (score 0):

based on B.Tanner answer this is a script  which tests every 60 seconds , if any file has changed , it will create a backup, you should have 2 folders backups/OLD and backups/current

```
while true  
do 
DEST=/home/$USER/backups         # the name my backup media is mounted under
if [ -n "$(rsync -ai --delete  --exclude ".[!.]*"  $(pwd)/ $DEST/current)" ]; then
    DATE=`date +"%m-%d-%y"`
    TIME=`date +"%T"`
    mkdir -p $DEST/OLD/$DATE
    mkdir $DEST/OLD/$DATE/$TIME
    cp -al $DEST/current/ $DEST/OLD/$DATE/$TIME
    echo "done:$DATE/$TIME"
fi
sleep 60   
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The rsync program already has backup options that do what you want.

This is the script that I use for backups, running as root at 23:45 each day:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
# This is run as root at the end of the day

(   echo ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" $(date)
    today=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
    month=$(date +%Y-%m)
    # USB backups
    cd /media/ray/Backup-Ray
    rsync --archive --one-file-system --delete --backup \
        --backup-dir="../../$today/etc" "/etc/" "mostrecent/etc/"
    rsync --archive --one-file-system --delete --backup \
        --backup-dir="../../$today/home" \
        --exclude=".config/google-chrome/" \
        --exclude=".local/share/zeitgeist/" \
        --exclude=".cache/" --exclude="Trash/" --exclude="Downloads/" \
        "/home/" "mostrecent/home/"
    rsync --archive --ignore-existing $today/ $month/
    echo "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<" $(date)
) &>>/home/ray/Log/root.out

exit 0
```

All changed and deleted files are preserved.
It's easy to use the standard unix tools to examine and recover files:

```
$ cd /media/ray/Backup-Ray
$ ls -l {,*}/home/ray/public/Log/wait.xhtml
-rw-r--r-- 1 ray ray 14002 Dec  3 21:04 2018-12-16/home/ray/public/Log/wait.xhtml
-rw-r--r-- 1 ray ray 14102 Dec 16 09:28 2018-12-17/home/ray/public/Log/wait.xhtml
-rw-r--r-- 1 ray ray 14202 Dec 17 20:47 2018-12-20/home/ray/public/Log/wait.xhtml
-rw-r--r-- 1 ray ray 14302 Dec 20 15:12 2018-12-25/home/ray/public/Log/wait.xhtml
-rw-r--r-- 1 ray ray 14402 Dec 25 21:21 2018-12-26/home/ray/public/Log/wait.xhtml
-rw-r--r-- 1 ray ray 14002 Dec  3 21:04 2018-12/home/ray/public/Log/wait.xhtml
-rw-r--r-- 1 ray ray 14452 Dec 26 18:43 /home/ray/public/Log/wait.xhtml
-rw-r--r-- 1 ray ray 14452 Dec 26 18:43 mostrecent/home/ray/public/Log/wait.xhtml
```

Only the "mostrecent" directory is large.

The monthly accumulation directory (2018-12) contains the oldest changes throughout the month.  It isn't necessary to do this step, but when I need to save space it allows me to delete all the daily updates for that month (A year from now I might care what things looked like at the end of December, but not so much how things changed within the month.)

Obviously you'd need to change the frequency, timestamps, etc., and add your portability code, but the same mechanism should do what you want.