# Delete all but newest file of format 08-20-2018_01:24-PM

Tags: bash, scripts, 18.04, ubuntu-mate

I use this to make it easier to see when a backup script ran.

```
touch /media/andy/MAXTOR_SDB1/Ubuntu_Mate_18.04/$( date '+%m-%d-%Y_%I:%M-%p' )
```

I would like a script that would delete all but the newest file ONLY of this type 08-20-2018_01:24-PM

Comment: What tool are you using for the backup

Comment: It will be much simpler if you choose a date format that sorts lexically in your locale - for example, `%Y%m%d_%H%M`

Comment: @George Udosen I use a backup script I made.

Answer (score 2):

First I would suggest to use date and time format that will be parsed more easy. For example:

```
$ date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M'
2018-08-21_21:41
```

Then you can use something as the follow, to keep only the newest file  ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6844785/6543935)):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
TARGET_DIR='./'
REGEX='[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}'   # regular expression that match to: date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M'
LATEST_FILE="$(ls "$TARGET_DIR" | egrep "^${REGEX}$" | tail -1)"
find "$TARGET_DIR" ! -name "$LATEST_FILE" -type f -regextype egrep -regex ".*/${REGEX}$" -exec rm -f {} +
```

---

If you want to delete a number of files that are older than a period of time you could use something as this ([source of the idea](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029653/566421)):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
TARGET_DIR='./'
MAX_AGE='3 days ago'
AGE="$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M' --date="$MAX_AGE")"

for file in "$TARGET_DIR"/*
do
    CLR="$(echo $(basename "$file") | sed -e 's/-//g' -e 's/_//g' -e 's/://g')"

    if [[ -f $file ]] && [[ $AGE -ge $CLR ]] 2>/dev/null
    then
        rm -f "$file"
    fi 
done
```

---

Another option is to use `find` and delete the files older than a period of time, based on their date of creation. For example the next command will delete all files older than 2 days:

```bsh
find /path/ -mtime +2 -type f -delete
```

---

Ideas for complete backup scrips could be found at:

- https://github.com/pa4080/simple-backup-solutions

Comment: To perform my tests, I've used this command to generate a couple of empty files: `for i in {0..10}; do touch $(LC_TIME=C date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M' --date="$i days ago") -d "$i days ago"; done`

Comment: I prefer month day year format. (I'm American)