# Ubuntu server back to a couple of days ago

Tags: server, 18.04, backup

I am having trouble with my linux server. Yesterday I created a lot of directories and files that i no longer want/need. Is there a way to restore my system back to how it was a couple of days ago?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not generally. Have you got any backup from that time?

Comment: No. I think i have learnt my lesson with this one. I didn't think i needed it as i have just started and experimenting with Ubuntu server. But i went to far to just reinstall the OS. Going to make automatic backups from now on.

Comment: If what you created (directories and files) were not in a system directory; you could always `find -delete` them  (where you use a -mtime possibly to limit the results to the last 24 (48, 72) hours.  Use the `find` firstly to verify the results, then add the -delete to actually delete what it found.  This is a rough idea  (the find could also match some system files, logs etc that were modified in that time period, why I mentioned the non-system-directory at the start; though this too could possibly be worked around).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am going to give that a try. I take it that you can select from the list which ones you can delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it is not possible, if there isn't setup any preliminary backup solution.

For example if you are using [LVM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) you can create snapshots of your file-system before taking steps that you would like to cancel later on. In case it is not possible to setup LVM you can use some other backup solution. Here are presented few examples: [Simple Backup Solution](https://askubuntu.com/q/1028321/566421). Also here are presented the solutions that I'm using on my Ubuntu systems: https://github.com/pa4080/simple-backup-solutions

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately i don't have any back ups atm. As i have just started on the server edition. Ill follow these steps in the future.