# batch FreeFileSync job with crontab

Tags: command-line, permissions, cron

I need to set up an automatic sync between a folder on my Disk and my google Drive, that runs every day, using FreeFileSync.

I created a batch job from FreeFileSync, named `syncDrive.ffs_batch`, and saved in my FreeFileSync installation folder `/home/$USER/bin/FreeFileSync`.

the job doesn't work for some reason. I've set up the crontab file as follows:

```
DISPLAY=:10.0
0 18 * * * /home/$USER/bin/FreeFileSync/syncDrive.ffs_batch
```

if I manually run the script from terminal, i get a permission error. If i run it with sudo, it says command not found.

Anyone knows how to fix? thanks in advance. Using Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: What command does it say is "not found"? the `syncDrive.ffs_batch` script, or a command within that script? Did you make `syncDrive.ffs_batch` executable?

Comment: FWIW I don't think that `$USER` is set by default in the crontab environment - however `$LOGNAME` should be (as well as `$HOME` - which you could use in place of `/home/$USER`)

Comment: I'm using FreeFileSync under Windows, I like it much. But I feel obliged to tell you the command `rsync` is much better choice for scripting under Linux. Here is one crazy cool advanced example: https://askubuntu.com/a/1029653/566421

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the command in your crontab to something like:

```
0 18 * * *   DISPLAY=:0 /home/your-username/bin/FreeFileSync /home/your-username/bin/FreeFileSync/Sync.ffs_batch
```

to provide full path to the FreeFileSync executable (`/home/your-username/bin/FreeFileSync`) and to its job-file (`/home/your-username/bin/FreeFileSync/Sync.ffs_batch`).

Comment: Thank you, I'll try in that way. Anyway, do you have any clue on why the simple command doesn't work alone?

Comment: The *ffs_batch* files are XML, so they are not executables. So it will not work this way. You need to call an application to open the file (in this case FreeFileSync to open *ffs_batch*).

Comment: This got rid of an error I was receiving when running via cron: "Error: Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?"

Comment: @kindaran you have to debug this by yourself. There may be some changes in FFS. At first try switching to Xorg.

Comment: @N0rbert I'm saying that your suggestion resolved the error I was receiving and now FFS runs just fine via cron. Not sure what you are commenting on.

Comment: Was a bit tired, thank you for your feedback, @kindaran :)